# Convert screen coordinate to window coordinate in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspoint

I've seen this question asked multiple times here, and I tried some answers, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
NSPoint pnt = [[self window] convertScreenToBase:[NSEvent mouseLocation]];
```

I'm using above code to do my conversion, but I get same coordinates for pnt.x and pnt.y no matter where mouse location is.

I noticed that this method is deprecated, but it should still work I guess, right?

Does anyone have any good suggestion on how I can do this conversion?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You should use `[[self window] mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]` instead.

Comment: it doesn't work...behaves same way as convertScreenToBase

Comment: found the BUG!!! My bad! Thank you so much! I was using the wrong window! duh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]` instead.

Comment: Try providing some more information on what that does that makes it a better candidate to resolve the problem.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explanation to your intension.

Comment: @BrandonBuck: The method does precisely what the question was trying to do. It returns the mouse location in the coordinates of a window rather than the screen ("converted" as it were). I'm having a hard time imagining what more can be said. Also, the questioner already indicated in the comments that it solved their problem.

Comment: Bam, "`[window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]` will return the mouse coordinates in the context of the window instead of the screen like you're looking for. Here's a very short example of how you'd employ this method ...". I'll be honest, when I get SO questions as search results, the first thing I do is look at answers and answers like this mean nothing to me because it's just a method call. While you are answering the question asked, you also have to think about who else might see this page - you're answering their questions as well.